# Request header field Authorization is not allowed (AngularJS rest api request)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

I have application written in AngularJS. I want to get access to FlightAware API. I use the following code:

```
  let Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

  let username = 'x';
  let apiKey = 'y';
  let fxmlUrl = 'https://flightxml.flightaware.com/json/FlightXML3/'

  let client_options = {
    user: username,
    password: apiKey
  }
  let client = new Client(client_options);

  client.registerMethod('findFlights', fxmlUrl + 'FindFlight', 'GET');
  client.registerMethod('weatherConditions', fxmlUrl + 'WeatherConditions', 'GET');

  let findFlightArgs = {
    parameters: {
        origin: 'KIAH',
        destination: 'KJFK',
        type: 'nonstop'
    }
  }

  let weatherConditionsArgs = {
    parameters: {
        airport_code: 'KHOU'
    }
  }

  client.methods.weatherConditions(weatherConditionsArgs, function (data, response) {
    console.log('Current conditions at Hobby Airport: %j', data.WeatherConditionsResult.conditions[0]);
  })
```

When I execute it in nodeJS it works but in my AngularJS app I get an error:
`Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I found some information that this error is connected with CORS but the server side is the same regardless I use AngularJS or NodeJS in order to run the code. How can I execute it without an error in AngularJS?

Comment: Check to see if the request header contains the following: `Accept: application/xml`?

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. By the way the response is in json format.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says, that the FlightXML server (https://flightxml.flightaware.com) does not set the corresponding CORS headers, which would be necessary to run from a browser. (CORS is "on", if browser application running from http://yoursite.com fetches data from another host, such https://flightxml.flightaware.com)

CORS restrictions apply only applications running *in* *browser*. So the "same" JavaScript code running on NodeJS (server side) won't have such restriction.

Unfortunately, it is necessary for external server to set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` header, otherwise your browser-based scenario won't work. So looks like that FlightXML does not support your scenario.

As a fix, I suggest you to create a server-side proxy, so

1. your browser-side code does not read data directly from flightxml, but calls some HTTP endpoint of your own server, eg `http://yoursite.com/weather?args...`.
2. your server code connects to flightxml (no CORS restrictions) and simply returns the data wanted